# ValueError: Input X contains NaN

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I'm training to classify my traffic using SVM ML..as below

```
import pandas as pd # for process the DataSet
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
ds= pd.read_csv("dataset_sdn.csv") # to read the dataset with name (ds)
ds.fillna(0)
ds #
```

[ds output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RR8K.png)

```
X = ds.iloc[: , [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,17,18,19,20,21]]   # Input Features  
Y = ds.iloc[:, 22]  # OutPut
print (X)
print (Y)
```

[X output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggh9d.png)

[Y output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29MCf.png)

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_Train, X_Test, Y_Train, Y_Test = train_test_split (X, Y, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
X_Train = sc_X.fit_transform(X_Train)
X_Test = sc_X.transform(X_Test)

from sklearn.svm import SVC
classifier = SVC (kernel='linear', random_state=0)
classifier.fit(X_Train, Y_Train)
Y_pred = classifier.predict(X_Test)
```

here in this last step i get error message

---

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) Input In [43], in <cell line: 3>()
> 1 from sklearn.svm import SVC
> 2 classifier = SVC (kernel='linear', random_state=0)
> ----> 3 classifier.fit(X_Train, Y_Train)
> 5 # The output predect
> 6 Y_pred = classifier.predict(X_Test)
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm_base.py:173,
> in BaseLibSVM.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
> 171     check_consistent_length(X, y)
> 172 else:
> --> 173     X, y = self._validate_data(
> 174         X,
> 175         y,
> 176         dtype=np.float64,
> 177         order="C",
> 178         accept_sparse="csr",
> 179         accept_large_sparse=False,
> 180     )
> 182 y = self._validate_targets(y)
> 184 sample_weight = np.asarray(
> 185     [] if sample_weight is None else sample_weight, dtype=np.float64
> 186 )
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:596,
> in BaseEstimator._validate_data(self, X, y, reset,
> validate_separately, **check_params)
> 594         y = check_array(y, input_name="y", **check_y_params)
> 595     else:
> --> 596         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
> 597     out = X, y
> 599 if not no_val_X and check_params.get("ensure_2d", True):
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:1074,
> in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order,
> copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output,
> ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)    1069
> estimator_name = _check_estimator_name(estimator)    1070     raise
> ValueError(    1071         f"{estimator_name} requires y to be
> passed, but the target y is None"    1072     )
> -> 1074 X = check_array(    1075     X,    1076     accept_sparse=accept_sparse,    1077
> accept_large_sparse=accept_large_sparse,    1078     dtype=dtype,
> 1079     order=order,    1080     copy=copy,    1081
> force_all_finite=force_all_finite,    1082     ensure_2d=ensure_2d,
> 1083     allow_nd=allow_nd,    1084
> ensure_min_samples=ensure_min_samples,    1085
> ensure_min_features=ensure_min_features,    1086
> estimator=estimator,    1087     input_name="X",    1088 )    1090 y =
> _check_y(y, multi_output=multi_output, y_numeric=y_numeric, estimator=estimator)    1092 check_consistent_length(X, y)
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:899,
> in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype,
> order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd,
> ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator, input_name)
> 893         raise ValueError(
> 894             "Found array with dim %d. %s expected <= 2."
> 895             % (array.ndim, estimator_name)
> 896         )
> 898     if force_all_finite:
> --> 899         _assert_all_finite(
> 900             array,
> 901             input_name=input_name,
> 902             estimator_name=estimator_name,
> 903             allow_nan=force_all_finite == "allow-nan",
> 904         )
> 906 if ensure_min_samples > 0:
> 907     n_samples = _num_samples(array)
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:146,
> in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, msg_dtype, estimator_name,
> input_name)
> 124         if (
> 125             not allow_nan
> 126             and estimator_name    (...)
> 130             # Improve the error message on how to handle missing values in
> 131             # scikit-learn.
> 132             msg_err += (
> 133                 f"\n{estimator_name} does not accept missing values"
> 134                 " encoded as NaN natively. For supervised learning, you might want"    (...)
> 144                 "#estimators-that-handle-nan-values"
> 145             )
> --> 146         raise ValueError(msg_err)
> 148 # for object dtype data, we only check for NaNs (GH-13254)
> 149 elif X.dtype == np.dtype("object") and not allow_nan:
>
> ValueError: Input X contains NaN. SVC does not accept missing values
> encoded as NaN natively. For supervised learning, you might want to
> consider sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingClassifier and Regressor
> which accept missing values encoded as NaNs natively. Alternatively,
> it is possible to preprocess the data, for instance by using an
> imputer transformer in a pipeline or drop samples with missing values.
> See https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html You can find a
> list of all estimators that handle NaN values at the following page:
> https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html#estimators-that-handle-nan-values

So, plz any advice to solve this error, although there isn't any NaN value in the dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not replacing old dataframe with new dataframe.

Use this:

```
ds = ds.fillna(0)
```

OR

```
ds.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check the dataframe columns types are the same as what your model was trained on.  Ex. int vs object.

```
df.dtypes
```